# 12v to 5v + 3.3v regulation capacitors help

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ldo

I am using a K7805 buck converter module to drop 12v down to 5v, with a ceramic capacitor on the input and output as per the datasheet.

Directly after this i have am AMS1117-3.3 to give me the 3.3v out.

I have a couple of questions as what i am finding online doesnt match with what the data sheet says.

1-I have seen that people recommend electrolytic capacitors in addition to the ceramics?
2- I have seen people putting additional capacitors on the input of the AMS1117, is this still needed with the capacitor on the back of the K7805?

[AMS1117 Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811142212_Advanced-Monolithic-Systems-AMS1117-3-3_C6186.pdf)

[K7805 Datasheet](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/K7805-500R3.html)

Below is the schematic as per both datasheets with the separate power circuits in each box.

C4&C5 are ceramic
C6 is Tantalum

[image: schematic]

Comment: 1) Additional capacitors, where exactly? Draw a diagram or refer to some datasheet or diagram. 2) It depends, how far apart are the regulators and where are the capacitors located? A PCB layout would explain this. Also, why would anyone put tantalum caps in a modern circuit?

Comment: Apparently the 10uF and 22uF on the k7805 are supposed to be ceramic with an electrolytic on the outside edge of each, the tantalum is recommended as per the data sheet

Comment: The DS says: *, increased values and/or tantalum or low ESR electrolytic capacitors*

Comment: Just a note, if you properly local-bypass-cap each other section in the design, it could lessen the demands here (and likely reduce trace EMI.)  I'd draw the schematic with unpopulated extra capacitors, and measure the effectiveness during optimization stage; if another had to be added, it could easily.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, check the linked datasheet. This is apparently not a 7805, but a buck converter intended as a drop-in replacement for a 7805.

Comment: @robbrown92, think of it this way: Adding capacitor locations to a circuit board (and maybe not stuffing them) is often cheaper than re-designing and re-fabricating a circuit board when you find out you need capacitors that weren't included in the design.

Comment: @ThePhoton. You are right.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the board will be fabbed with smd capacitors so ill add in a few extra slots and hand solder them in if required

Comment: last question would it affect the running of the board if I just included extra capacitors?